# Connection to Oracle Database using ODP.NET with empty proxy password

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle12c, odp.net

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer to connect to certain DB using for example following credentials (note that Proxy Password is empty):

```
Username: abcdefg
Password: 123123
Hostname: 11.22.33.44
Port:     1234
Service name: very.cool.com
Proxy type: User Name
Proxy Client: cool_name
Proxy Password: <-- yes, empty password
```

And it's working fine. Now I'm developing Windows Forms App in C# that is using ODP.NET to connect to the Oracle DB.

The issue is that when i use the following connection string:

```
connectionStringBuilder.DataSource = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=11.22.33.44)(PORT=1234))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=very.cool.com)))";
connectionStringBuilder.UserID = "abcdefg";
connectionStringBuilder.Password = "123123";
connectionStringBuilder.ProxyUserId = "cool_name";
```

I get the following error during connection:

> ORA-01005: null password giver; logon denied

The same is when I try:

```
connectionStringBuilder.ProxyPassword = "";
```

Using (or other placeholder password):

```
connectionStringBuilder.ProxyPassword = " "; // space instead of empty string
```

I got error

> ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

However when I try to connect to different Oracle DB that is not using proxy credentials the connection is working fine and I'm able to run queries etc so it shouldn't be problem of wrongly written code or wrong libraries.

Is there some way to overcome the ProxyPassword problem?

- Oracle DB version: 12c
- .NET Framework 4.6

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/featConnecting.htm#i1006514) says *ODP.NET applications can use proxy authentication by setting the "Proxy User Id" and "Proxy Password" attributes in the connection string.* - locks like Proxy Password must not be empty. I would consider this as a bug in ODP.NET

Comment: Worth to point out that in Oracle SQL Developer empty password is threated the same as "   " (few spaces) and "   asd   " is the same as "asd" (regardles if we are talking about user password or proxy password) but it is different in ODP.NET connection string where white spaces makes difference. Seems like ODP.NET as @WernfriedDomscheit pointed out is lacking some features or just uses different business rules.

Comment: Having a null password surely is a MASSIVE audit fail and security risk?

Comment: @DominicCotton Yes, lack of password makes an issue but security is not the subject of the question.